# Python: How to Install OpenCV on Google cloud functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Google cloud functions Gen2 and Python 3.10 and the latest version of gcloud cli and `opencv-python==4.6.0.66` and `functions-framework==3.2.0`

I can't deploy on google cloud, because `import cv2` is causing this error

```
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at .import_module ( /opt/python3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126 )
at .bootstrap ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py:153 )
at .<module> ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py:181 )
at .<module> ( /workspace/functions.py:20 )
at .<module> ( /workspace/endpoints.py:9 )
at .<module> ( /workspace/main.py:2 )
at ._call_with_frames_removed ( <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241 )
at .exec_module ( <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:883 )
at .create_app ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py:289 )
at ._cli ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/_cli.py:37 )
at .invoke ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py:760 )
at .invoke ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py:1404 )
at .main ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py:1055 )
at .__call__ ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py:1130 )
at .<module> ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework:8 )
```

If I use `opencv-python-headless` instead, I get this error

```
ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library
at .load ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyzbar/zbar_library.py:65 )
at .load_libzbar ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py:127 )
at .zbar_function ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py:148 )
at .<module> ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py:151 )
at .<module> ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyzbar/pyzbar.py:7 )
at .<module> ( /workspace/functions.py:22 )
at .<module> ( /workspace/endpoints.py:9 )
at .<module> ( /workspace/main.py:2 )
at ._call_with_frames_removed ( <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241 )
at .exec_module ( <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:883 )
at .create_app ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py:289 )
at ._cli ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/_cli.py:37 )
at .invoke ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py:760 )
at .invoke ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py:1404 )
at .main ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py:1055 )
at .__call__ ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py:1130 )
at .<module> ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework:8 )
```

OpenCV is a must-have requirement. Can this error be fixed or should I deploy the project elsewhere?

Comment: I have no experience with google cloud functions, but you receive this error because you don't have opengl install on system.
You can either install libgl or user opencv build without opengl

Comment: @aramcpp unfortunately, that's not possible on Google cloud functions as far as I know. Since I don't have access to package managers in order to install OS dependencies. I can only add pip dependencies.

Comment: Can you change opencv-python to opencv-python-headless? (https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python-headless/)
As far as I know it doesn't require libgl

Comment: @aramcpp If I use `opencv-python-headless` I get a different error `ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library` - pasted the error trace in the question

Comment: Do you have any other requirements besides opencv-python-headless?
Because I don't see zbar being required by opencv

Comment: @aramcpp I have many other requirements, but only opencv seems to be causing issues so far

Comment: error with zbar is caused by pyzbar package as you can see in logs

Comment: this might be helpful
https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/issues/40

Comment: @aramcpp Ah! so answer this question, i'll accept your answer and I'll handle the pyzbar issue separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum up of the problem

First error with libgl can be solved by installing opencv-python-headless (which is CPU only, and doesn't require libgl)

pyzbar in the same way requires zbar to be installed.
[(can't be done in cloud functions environment)](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/issues/40)

Comment: seems I have to use an alternative to Google cloud functions after all